# Scheduled NSTimer's selector called with delay in iOS

Tags: ios, scheduled-tasks, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have an `NSTimer` that should be running all the time the app is active. It is intended to show a countdown that depends on certain user's actions. I fire this timer this way:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(notifyTimerTick:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
```

Then, in the method `notifyTimerTick:`, I update the countdown label I show to users and, if the countdown is over, I invalidate the timer, I look for a new countdown, and I fire the timer again.

I'm not having troubles being the UI blocked doing this way, but on the other hand, I've found that sometimes the `notifyTimerTick:` selector call is significantly delayed: I have a view that takes a couple of seconds to be completely loaded, and I've seen that timer's selector is not called until the corresponding view controller's `viewDidLoad` delegate method is called.

I've read several posts dealing with timers blocking the UI, but I'm not sure how to deal with a timer getting blocked by the UI... what the best way to handle this should be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different run loop mode.

When you use the ScheduledtimerWithTimeInterval class method, the timer is scheduled on the current run loop.

Instead do something like this:

```
NSTimer *labelTick = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:labelTick forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tested your code, but it still seems that timer's countdown is blocked... could that be because I'm firing the timer within another view controller? Should I better have the timer property declared in `AppDelegate` and handle the timer there?

Comment: Your code is attaching the timer to the main thread, right? Should I fire the timer from a different thread?